# Wp Some Pages content Not display in editor after move live server

Tags: wordpress, editor, wysiwyg

We work on multi site which one working well on local.

But i have make site on live server then some pages content not display on wysiwyg editor backend but display on front side.

we have use Version 4.2.4

How to fix this one this is wp bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Change config.php working fine.

```
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
//define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
to
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

Whats difference between utf8mb4 vs utf8 on wp.